# what is a differential i/o

Tags: fpga

In the world of the Spartan 3E Fpga the documentation says

> Most pins can be paired together to form differential I/Os.

The question is: What is a differential Input/Output?

Comment: Do you have a question not covered by the wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling

Comment: This question belongs on the [electronics and robotics stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: So then this is about differental signaling. Kewlio, that actually answers my question.

Comment: Since the answer in wikipedia does not contain the keywords "differential I/O" google would not have been able anyone to that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, differential i/o is about differential signaling:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling